# How to format Computed Field as WKT (geofield CCK) with display code

Tags: entities, location

I'm pretty green here. This is my first question!

I am using computed field to calculate a WKT (Well known text) geofield using the geocoder API. This calculation is being done correctly, giving a result such as "POINT (28.12866 46.17625)".

When I want to display this computed field the only have the following options:

- Unsanitized
- Plaintext
- Raw value, no display code
- Filtered Markup
- -Hidden-

I currently have the following display code, which I think it the problem:

```
$display_output = $entity_field_item['value'];
```

I don't know how to make the normal geofield formatters available to display this field, so for example I can render it as a map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Geofield calculates various values with the geofield_compute_values() functions (see README), so calculating a WKT will not replace it properly. Geocoder supports computed field, so I guess you can use that to populate a geofield.